# Delete form.io submissions older than n days

Tags: formio

On our form.io instance, we need to delete all user submissions older than n days (for data protection reasons).

What is the best way to achieve that? Is there an (undocumented) batch DELETE method in the api? Something like

```
DELETE {{projectUrl}}/{{formPath}}/submission?data.created_lt={{date}}
```

Am i missing any other option?

Answer (score 1):

https://apidocs.form.io/#1f207caa-9d04-3e81-2973-e4bf82ee5190

It seems like you can query against submissions in a form, so if there is no undocumented batch delete, you could still find all of the submissions that need to be deleted and delete them one by one.

> To query for specific submissions
> In order to find specific submissions within the index, you can also perform queries for any poperty within a submission. [...] So, lets say you wish to find all people in the submissions who have the last name of Smith, you would run the following query:

> `{{appUrl}}/register/submission?data.lastName=Smith`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is what we decided to implement and it really seems to be the only option (for now).